# ReadFile Function doesn't Read Files Correctly - Win32 API

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, file, winapi

As a part of my Win32 learning, I created a simple program that writes to an existing file named `file1.txt` and after that, reads from this file to a buffer and displays the buffer on a console. The file's content starts with `Hello`. The problem will be discussed after the code. This is the code (written in C++/Win32 on Visual Studio 2017):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int _argc, TCHAR *_argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = false;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"file1.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER size, physize;
    DWORD fptr = 0;
    BYTE buff[] = " World";

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "File created!\n";

    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);
    cout << "File Size: " << size.QuadPart << "\n";

    physize.LowPart = GetCompressedFileSize(L"File1.txt", (LPDWORD)&physize.HighPart);
    cout << "Physical Size: " << physize.QuadPart << "\n";

    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, (PLONG)&fptr, FILE_END);
    WriteFile(hFile, buff, (DWORD)strlen((const char *)buff), &fptr, NULL);

    WaitForSingleObject(hFile, INFINITE);

    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, (PLONG)&fptr, FILE_BEGIN);
    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);
    cout << "Size now is: " << size.QuadPart << "\n";

    BYTE *buff2 = new BYTE[size.QuadPart + 1];
    buff2[size.QuadPart] = '\0';

    if (!ReadFile(hFile, (LPVOID)buff2, size.QuadPart, &fptr, NULL)) 
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << buff2 << "\n";

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    delete[] buff2, buff;
    return 0;
}
```

After the writing, the file's content is `Hello World`. But the output in the console is:

```
File created!
File Size: 5
Physical Size: 5
Size now is: 11
═══════════
```

I searched the Web and even this website and didn't find any solution that helped me. In my opinion, the problem is in the reading because the writing has been completed successfully. I even used the function `WaitForSignalObject` to make sure the writing is ended. Is there something I missed? Thank you for the help.

P.S. My friend has been banned from asking questions in this site, what can he do to remove the ban and continue using the site?

P.S.2 I'm sorry if there is any grammar mistake, English isn't my native language.

Comment: Related to the question ban: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: What is the `WaitForSingleObject` for??

Comment: @jab A file handle (like any other kernel object handle) can be waited on. Though hardly anyone does since the semantics of when a file handle gets signaled don't generally coincide with what a developer needs (or expects).

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I know, but apparently the OP doesn't

Comment: You never even went so far as to explain,*what* the problem is. Read [ask] and make sure your question contains the expected behavior in addition to the observed behavior. Unrelated to your issue: All your calls to `GetLastError` return meaningless values at the time you're calling it.

Comment: @jab Incidentally, `WaitForSingleObject` does what the OP expects. They may not know why, and consequently when it stops working, though - as implemented - it happens to work.

Comment: I see the problem is the output is `═══════════` instead of `Hello World`

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure what the OP expects.

Comment: @IInspectable, not all kernel object types are waitable -- just types that support `SYNCHRONIZE` access. Most common types are waitable, including File objects, but a few are not, such as Key, Token, Section, WindowStation, and Desktop. That said, calling `WaitForSingleObject` on a file that's opened in *synchronous mode* is pointless. The I/O manager itself waits on a sychronous File object for the I/O request to complete, so `WriteFile` won't return until the write is complete.

Comment: You never check if the seek to the start fails. Why SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES? The compressed size is irrelevant. You define UNICODE too late.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your file pointer a bit too far here:

```
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, (PLONG)&fptr, FILE_BEGIN);
```

According to docs for [SetFilePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer), the third parameter is:

> lpDistanceToMoveHigh
>
> A pointer to the high order 32-bits of the signed 64-bit distance to move.
> If you do not need the high order 32-bits, this pointer must be set to NULL.

You are setting the move's low order 32-bits to 0, and the high order 32-bits to the value of `fptr`, which is not 0 when this line is reached.  So, you are not moving to offset 0, like you think you are.

Did you mean:

```
SetFilePointer(hFile, fptr, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

or:

```
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

I strongly suggest to get rid of TCHAR stuff; it has no place in today's world. Just use `char` and `wchar_t` explicitly, you should know what do you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that the third argument of `SetFilePointer` is the file pointer and the third argument is the High part of the bytes to move. By the way, does it matter if I use "TCHAR" or "wchar_t"? Because the definition is `typedef wchar_t TCHAR`.

Comment: @Matan the definition of TCHAR depends on your `#define _UNICODE`. At some point MS thought that it would be convenient - you use `TCHAR` everywhere and they will turn it into an "appropriate" type. However, you should (must?) know that yourself, and their guess may fail. Besides, you are using your defines wrong (too late, after including `<tchar.h>`, as one of the comments above pointed out. Instead of fixing it, I'd rather remove it.

Comment: I swear I saw an upvote on my answer earlier! Regardless, my point was - it looked like OP wanted to specify an offset, but placed it into wrong argument (high part instead of low).

Comment: @VladFeinstein I upvoted when I first saw the answer posted, then I retracted when I actually read it and misinterpreted what it was saying, so it went to -1 instead of 0. But then I realized I misinterpreted and deleted that comment, but the retraction stayed. Your answer is pointing at the correct issue, but does not explain WHY the code is wrong, so I stand by the -1 now. If you edit your answer to elaborate more, I can upvote again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - appreciate your comment, and your answer is certainly superior. Thank you!

Comment: @VladFeinstein I expanded your answer a little more and then upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your misuse of `fptr` with `SetFilePointer()`.

`fptr` is set to 0 initially.  So, when you call `SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, (PLONG)&fptr, FILE_END)`, you are telling it to seek to offset `low:0,high:0 = 0` from the end of the file.  So the file pointer gets positioned at offset 5, as expected.  `SetFilePointer()` outputs the new file position to you, so `fptr` gets updated to the high 32bits of offset 5, which is 0 again.

Then you `WriteFile()` new data to the file, but you are using `fptr` to receive the number of bytes actually written.  So now `fptr` is updated to 6 (assuming `WriteFile()` is successful, which you are not checking for).

Then, you are passing `fptr` to `SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, (PLONG)&fptr, FILE_BEGIN)` as the high part.  So, instead of telling it to seek to offset `low:0,high:0 = 0` from the beginning of the file, you are actually telling it to seek to offset `low:0,high=6 = 0x600000000 = 25769803776` from the beginning.

Then you try to read `size` (11) bytes from offset 25769803776 instead of offset 0, and of course there is no valid data at that high offset, so your buffer gets filled with garbage instead.

The simplest fix is to reset `fptr` to 0 before seeking to `FILE_BEGIN`, eg:

```cpp
fptr = 0; // <-- add this
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, (PLONG)&fptr, FILE_BEGIN);
```

Or, you can simply omit the 3rd parameter altogether, since you are not dealing with a large file > 4GB in size:

```cpp
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_END); // offset 0 from end
...
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN); // offset 0 from beginning
```

If you want to support large files > 4GB properly, don't use separate variables for low and high parts, use `(U)LARGE_INTEGER` instead (like you already are for `GetFileSizeEx()` and `GetCompressedFileSize()`):

```cpp
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int _argc, TCHAR *_argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = false;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"file1.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER size, physize, fptr;
    BYTE buff[] = " World";
    DWORD written;

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "File created!\n";

    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);
    cout << "File Size: " << size.QuadPart << "\n";

    physize.LowPart = GetCompressedFileSize(L"File1.txt", (LPDWORD)&physize.HighPart);
    cout << "Physical Size: " << physize.QuadPart << "\n";

    fptr.QuadPart = 0;
    fptr.LowPart = SetFilePointer(hFile, fptr.LowPart, &fptr.HighPart, FILE_END);
    WriteFile(hFile, buff, (DWORD)strlen((const char *)buff), &written, NULL);

    fptr.QuadPart = 0;
    fptr.LowPart = SetFilePointer(hFile, fptr.LowPart, &fptr.HighPart, FILE_BEGIN);

    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);
    cout << "Size now is: " << size.QuadPart << "\n";

    BYTE *buff2 = new BYTE[size.QuadPart + 1];
    buff2[size.QuadPart] = '\0';

    if (!ReadFile(hFile, (LPVOID)buff2, size.QuadPart, &fptr, NULL)) 
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << buff2 << "\n";

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    delete[] buff2;

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can (and should) use [`SetFilePointerEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex) instead:

```cpp
LARGE_INTEGER ..., fptr;
fptr.QuadPart = 0;

SetFilePointerEx(hFile, fptr, NULL, FILE_END);
...
SetFilePointerEx(hFile, fptr, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```